# Why is the output is coming out to be zero for my friend operation overloaded code

Tags: c++, c++11

When I am trying to run this code I am getting the output to be zero which isn't expected, according to what I have defined I should get a -1 rather than a 0,I have tried changing the values of x,I have tried looking up for the garbage value if any. What you guys think?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class nf {
    int x;
public:
    nf() {
        x=1;
    }
    nf(int a) {
        a=x;
    }

    friend nf operator ++(nf n1) {
        n1.x=-n1.x;
    }
    void display() {
        cout<<x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    nf obj(1),obj2;
    obj2=++obj;
    obj2.display();
}
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) for the correct way to overload operators.

Comment: Well, I think that the TAB key on your keyboard appears to be broken, with the resulting code being somewhat unreadable, and hard to follow. You might wish to get your keyboard replaced, so that it's possible for you to cleanly, logically indent your code to make it readable to other people.

Comment: Just changed the alignment

Comment: @NathanOliver Why the output is coming to be 0?

Comment: @iCas I don't know what you did to change the alignment, but it didn't work.

Comment: @George The syntax and code seems fine it should work but no clue what went wrong.

Comment: @iCas Because you passed the object by *value*

Comment: @NathanOliver What alterations I should do to make it work?

Comment: Write the operator the right way like it shows in the Q&A I linked to.

Comment: Also, looks like `a=x;` should be `x=a;` or better yet `nf(int a) : x(a) {  }`

Comment: @NathanOliver I just saw the Q/A but i am not able to diagnose the error suggestions please?

Comment: @George Tried changing that but didn't work. The overloading of function isn't giving the desired output.

Comment: Increase the warning level of your compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class nf{
    int x;
    public:
    nf()
    {
        x=1;
    }
    nf(int a){
        x=a;
    }
friend nf operator ++(nf &n1)
{
    n1.x=-n1.x;
}
void display()
{
    cout<<x;
}



};
int main()
{
 nf c1;
 ++c1;
 c1.display();

}
```

Comment: `friend nf operator ++(nf &n1){ n1.x=-n1.x;}` -- Undefined behavior.  An `nf` is supposed to be returned, but nothing is returned.